# Meteor new boilerplate app via "meteor create" how to make it?

Tags: meteor

I wonder is there a way to create a new boilerplate app template and then use it like this:

```
meteor create simple-with-iron-router
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. yeoman generator for meteor https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-meteor
2. iron-cli by Evented Mind https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli
3. Meteor Kitchen - code generator for Meteor http://www.meteorkitchen.com/
4. "installer" atmosphere package https://atmospherejs.com/timbroddin/installer

Comment: such a nice tools you have found. I wish I could upvote your answer multiple times. Thank you! I will offer a bounty to get people attention!